# Unable to post right values to a c# webbrowser login form

Tags: c#

I am trying to login to a website to automate checking the status of a few items. The problem that I am having is that even though I manage to populate the usernname/password fields (I can see that the username is correct, password is masked), I get the message that

> the login credentials are incorrect

I have tried the following using the webbrowser component:

1. Manually enter the password and hit submit programmatically -failed
2. Manually enter username/password and hit submit programmatically -failed
3. Manually enter username/password and hit submit manually - got an error 
   message but logged in.

The HTML code for the form, is similar to the following:

```
<input id="User" type="text" name="usrname" data-bind="value:username,returnKey:loginPageC" onkeydown="ClearEMessage()" tabindex="1">

<input id="Password" type="text" name="pass" data-bind="value:password,returnKey:loginPageC" onkeydown="ClearEMessage()" tabindex="1">
```

I have tried the following code, I have made sure that the correct button is clicked. Any idea on what am I doing wrong here? Thanks!!

```
HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
HtmlElement userName = doc.GetElementById("User");
HtmlElement pass = doc.GetElementById("Password");
userName.SetAttribute("value", "user123");
pass.SetAttribute("value", "pass321");
 HtmlElementCollection elc = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)
{
  if (el.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit"))
  {
      el.InvokeMember("Click");
   }
}
```

Comment: Is the Webbrowser component a requirement or could you also use background processing with `HttpWebRequest`/`HttpWebResponse`? Have you checked with Fiddler how the requests look if done in real browser compared to your tool?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using ID not the name

```
HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
HtmlElement userName = doc.GetElementById("User");
HtmlElement pass = doc.GetElementById("Password");
userName.SetAttribute("value", "user123");
pass.SetAttribute("value", "pass321");
 HtmlElementCollection elc = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)
{
  if (el.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit"))
  {
      el.InvokeMember("Click");
   }
}
```

because you are trying to get the data by `GetElementById`

### Edit

You can also have a look on the [Selenium Webdriver with C#](http://james-prescott.com/2014/02/01/tutorial-setting-up-selenium-webdriver-visual-studio/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice, I have managed to solved this problem by using Fidler, getting the post string and then posting it to the webbrowser through the Navigate function
    webBrowser1.Navigate("URL", "", byte1, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-
    urlencoded");